# Save new upcoming e-mail as file to selected folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run this VBA code in VBA Outlook, and my main goal is to save any new upcoming mail as file to selected folder. However, when I run this script, it does nothing, it does not save any new upcoming e-mail. Maybe you can look at this, and help me with that? Thanks a lot.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set olItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Atts As Attachments
Dim Att As Attachment
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

If Item.Class = olMail Then
  Set NewMail = Item
End If

Set Atts = Item.Attachments

If Atts.Count > 0 Then
  For Each Att In Atts
    If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), “”) > 0 Then
      strPath = “selected path”
      strName = NewMail.Subject & ” ” & Chr(45) & ” ” & Att.FileName
      Att.SaveAsFile strPath & strName
    End If
  Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check my answer on this other question where I show how to set up a listener. It's relevant to your workflow here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637693/outlook-2016-select-script-window-in-rules-wizard-is-blank/51638058#51638058

Comment: Where is `olItems` declared?  It needs to be a Global outside of any Sub...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a subject doesn't contain invalid symbols that can't be used for filenames. Also make sure that you pass a valid sting which represents a file path.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
   Dim Atts As Attachments
   Dim Att As Attachment
   Dim strPath As String
   Dim strName As String
   
   If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Atts = Item.Attachments

     If Atts.Count > 0 Then
       For Each Att In Atts
         If InStr(LCase(Att.FileName), “”) > 0 Then
           strPath = “selected path”
           strName = NewMail.Subject & ” ” & Chr(45) & ” ” & Att.FileName
           Att.SaveAsFile strPath & strName
         End If
       Next
     End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Note, you may also consider handling the [Application.NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event which is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.